# How to distribute Enterprise Xamarin Forms IOS app to beta testers

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, beta-testing

I have developed a platform that will provide an Information Security service to Enterprise customers.  The front-end is a Xamarin Forms application.  A company signs up for the service and their Information Security team members install the app on their mobile devices.

I believe this use is not covered by the Apple Enterprise Developer program.  The apps are not stand-alone app-store type apps.  I cannot install by physically connecting the user’s iphone to my dev machine.

Is there a way to do this other than Test Flight?  I am using Visual Studio 2019 from a Windows 10 PC (with a Mac on the same network, of course).

Comment: The correct distribution method for this application is probably a B2B app. You can use TestFlight to provide test versions.  Enterprise distribution is not appropriate as the users are not employees of your organisation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Visual Studio App Center? Not sure if it will fit your exact deployment needs but it may be something to look at if you haven't. I've just started using it and have had some success... but also some headaches too. Android distribution is a breeze but IOS in any shape form or fashion makes it difficult outside of their app store in my opinion.